# Heatmap wont change based on time values on Leaflet (R Shiny)

Tags: r, time, shiny, leaflet, heatmap

I am planning on the make a heatmap that shows the change in activity of a depth over a selected period of time on R shiny. The problem I am currently running into is that the heatmap does not change over time. It keeps showing the initial plot over and over.

Here is the dataset I am using. It is from the `quake` dataset with a few modifications. I named this dataset called `quakes_mod.csv`

```
X1     lat   long  depth mag stations    quakes_cat    time
1   -20.42  181.62  562 4.8   41          High Depth    2020-12-04 05:45:32
2   -20.62  181.03  650 4.2   15          High Depth    2020-12-04 05:45:32
3   -26.00  184.10  42  5.4   43          No Depth     2020-12-04 05:45:32
4   -17.97  181.66  626 4.1   19          High Depth    2020-12-04 05:45:32
5   -20.42  181.96  649 4.0   11          High Depth    2020-12-04 05:45:32
6   -19.68  184.31  195 4.0   12          Low Depth     2020-12-04 05:45:32
7   -11.70  166.10  82  4.8   43          No Depth    2020-12-04 05:45:32
8   -28.11  181.93  194 4.4   15          Low Depth 2020-12-04 05:45:32
9   -28.74  181.74  211 4.7   35         Low Depth  2020-12-04 05:45:32
10  -17.47  179.59  622 4.3   19         High Depth 2020-12-01 08:22:42
```

Upon a `glimpse()`, `quakes_cat` is a `factor` type while, `time` is `dttm` in Pacific Standard Time

**Now for my full R shiny Code Below**

```
library(shiny)
library(xts)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)


df<-read_csv('data/quakes_mod.csv')%>%
  mutate(time=as.POSIXct(time))

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, 
             body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("basemap", width= "100%", height = "100%"),
  
  absolutePanel(
    sliderInput(
      "timeRange", label = "Choose Time Range:",
      min = as.POSIXct("2020-12-01 00:00:00"),
      max = as.POSIXct("2020-12-31 23:59:59"),
      value = c(as.POSIXct("2020-12-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2020-12-04 23:59:59")),
      timeFormat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", timezone='PST', ticks = F, animate = T
    ), draggable = TRUE, top = "80%", left = "40%")
  
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #filter the traffic data based on time selected by user
  filtered <- reactive({
    df[df$time>=input$timeRange[1]& df$time<=input$timeRange[2],]
  })
  
  #initial static content along with leaflet the way it should be initially
  output$basemap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron)
  })
  
  #updating the markers real time
  observeEvent(input$timeRange,
               leafletProxy("basemap", data=filtered()) %>%
                 clearHeatmap() %>%
                 addHeatmap(lng=df$long,lat=df$lat,
                            max=3,radius=3,blur=3,intensity=df$quakes_cat,gradient= "OrRd")
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, upon observing my heatmap, nothing has changed. The heatmap matter does not change based upon the time selected in the scroller. It just resorts to the heatmap that was initially plotted. I know for a fact that a few values in `depth` that were changed Can anyone be of assistance? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some changes to make the code display points based on the selected dates. It uses the results of the `filtered()` reactive rather than the full `df` data frame. The full data frame will display all the points, the filtered will display only those that are selected. I have changed the data so that the fully reproducible example will illustrate the functioning code. I used `dput` to make the data frame which is always better than pasting a text version of the data since there is no chance of ambiguity.

```
library(shiny)
library(xts)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(
    list(
        X1 = 1:10,
        lat = c(
            -20.42,
            -20.62,
            -26,
            -17.97,-20.42,
            -19.68,
            -11.7,
            -28.11,
            -28.74,
            -17.47
        ),
        long = c(
            181.62,
            181.03,
            184.1,
            181.66,
            181.96,
            184.31,
            166.1,
            181.93,
            181.74,
            179.59
        ),
        depth = c(562L, 650L, 42L, 626L, 649L, 195L, 82L, 194L,
                            211L, 622L),
        mag = c(4.8, 4.2, 5.4, 4.1, 4, 4, 4.8, 4.4, 4.7,
                        4.3),
        stations = c(41L, 15L, 43L, 19L, 11L, 12L, 43L, 15L, 35L,
                                 19L),
        quakes_cat = c(
            "High Depth",
            "High Depth",
            "No Depth",
            "High Depth",
            "High Depth",
            "Low Depth",
            "No Depth",
            "Low Depth",
            "Low Depth",
            "High Depth"
        ),
        time = c(
            "2020-12-01 05:45:32",
            "2020-12-04 05:45:32",
            "2020-12-04 05:45:32",
            "2020-12-06 05:45:32",
            "2020-12-09 05:45:32",
            "2020-12-11 05:45:32",
            "2020-12-15 05:45:32",
            "2020-12-18 05:45:32",
            "2020-12-20 05:45:32",
            "2020-12-30 08:22:42"
        )
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-10L)
)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
    tags$style(type = "text/css", "html,
             body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
    leafletOutput("basemap", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
    
    absolutePanel(
        sliderInput(
            "timeRange",
            label = "Choose Time Range:",
            min = as.POSIXct("2020-12-01 00:00:00"),
            max = as.POSIXct("2020-12-31 23:59:59"),
            value = c(
                as.POSIXct("2020-12-01 00:00:00"),
                as.POSIXct("2020-12-04 23:59:59")
            ),
            timeFormat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",
            timezone = 'PST',
            ticks = F,
            animate = T
        ),
        draggable = TRUE,
        top = "80%",
        left = "40%"
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    #filter the traffic data based on time selected by user
    filtered <- reactive({
        df[df$time >= input$timeRange[1] & df$time <= input$timeRange[2], ]
    })
    
    output$basemap <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>%
            addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron)
    })
    
    observeEvent(
        input$timeRange,
        {                    # do some work in a block and return a leafletProxy
            dff <- filtered()  # get the filtered data frame
            lfp <-             # and use this data to create the map
              leafletProxy("basemap", data = dff) %>%
              clearHeatmap() %>%
              addHeatmap(
                  lng = dff$long,
                  lat = dff$lat,
                  max = 3,
                  radius = 3,
                  blur = 3,
                  intensity = dff$quakes_cat,
                  gradient = "OrRd"
              )
            lfp  # return the leaflet proxy
        }
    )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I also added `library(leaflet.extras)` so the code runs.

Comment: I'm loading another dataset that has large datapoints. The map is flashing sometimes it renders. How do I reduce or stop it?

Comment: Impossible to say without the data. I suggest raising another question with all the details.